# Looping through an array of objects to create a list array

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach, array.prototype.map

I'm having trouble creating a list array from an array of objects. I'm not sure where I am going wrong. here is my problem:

Look up all the shoes across all the designers and list them out in an array of arrays with this format:

[[designer name, shoe name, price], [designer name, shoe name, price], ....] E.g.,

```html
const currentInventory = [
  {
    name: 'Brunello Cucinelli',
    shoes: [
      {name: 'tasselled black low-top lace-up', price: 1000},
      {name: 'tasselled green low-top lace-up', price: 1100},
      {name: 'plain beige suede moccasin', price: 950},
      {name: 'plain olive suede moccasin', price: 1050}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Gucci',
    shoes: [
      {name: 'red leather laced sneakers', price: 800},
      {name: 'black leather laced sneakers', price: 900}
    ]
  }
];

function renderInventory(inventory) {
 let arr = [];
 
 for(let i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++) {
   for(let j = 0;j < inventory[i].shoes.length; j++) {
     arr.push([`${inventory[i].name}, ${inventory[i].shoes[j].name}, ${inventory[i].shoes[j].price}`])
   }
 }
 
  return arr;
}
```

I am receiving this error and I am not sure why?

```
Expected $[0].length = 1 to equal 3. Expected $[0][0] = 'Brunello Cucinelli, tasselled black low-top lace-up, 1000' to equal 'Brunello Cucinelli'. Expected $[0][1] = undefined to equal 'tasselled black low-top lace-up'. Expected $[0][2] = undefined to equal 1000. Expected $[1].length = 1 to equal 3. Expected $[1][0] = 'Brunello Cucinelli, tasselled green low-top lace-up, 1100' to equal 'Brunello Cucinelli'. Expected $[1][1] = undefined to equal 'tasselled green low-top lace-up'. Expected $[1][2] = undefined to equal 1100. Expected $[2].length = 1 to equal 3. Expected $[2][0] = 'Brunello Cucinelli, plain beige suede moccasin, 950' to equal 'Brunello Cucinelli'. Expected $[2][1] = undefined to equal 'plain beige suede moccasin'. Expected $[2][2] = undefined to equal 950. Expected $[3].length = 1 to equal 3. Expected $[3][0] = 'Brunello Cucinelli, plain olive suede moccasin, 1050' to equal 'Brunello Cucinelli'. Expected $[3][1] = undefined to equal 'plain olive suede moccasin'. Expected $[3][2] = undefined to equal 1050. Expected $[4].length = 1 to equal 3. Expected $[4][0] = 'Gucci, red leather laced sneakers, 800' to equal 'Gucci'. Expected $[4][1] = undefined to equal 'red leather laced sneakers'. Expected $[4][2] = undefined to equal 800. Expected $[5].length = 1 to equal 3. Expected $[5][0] = 'Gucci, black leather laced sneakers, 900' to equal 'Gucci'. Expected $[5][1] = undefined to equal 'black leather laced sneakers'. Expected $[5][2] = undefined to equal 900.
```

Also,

I thought that I could possible use .map() and .reduce() to solve this problem as well but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Can you give an example of your desired strucutre

Comment: [[designer name, shoe name, price], [designer name, shoe name, price], ....] E.g.,

Comment: if you think one of the answers were helpful mark it as accepted, the button below down-upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for the length

```
for(let j = 0; j < inventory[i].shoes.length; j++) {
               ^^^^
```

```js
const currentInventory = [
  {
    name: 'Brunello Cucinelli',
    shoes: [
      {name: 'tasselled black low-top lace-up', price: 1000},
      {name: 'tasselled green low-top lace-up', price: 1100},
      {name: 'plain beige suede moccasin', price: 950},
      {name: 'plain olive suede moccasin', price: 1050}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Gucci',
    shoes: [
      {name: 'red leather laced sneakers', price: 800},
      {name: 'black leather laced sneakers', price: 900}
    ]
  }
];

function renderInventory(inventory) {
 let arr = [];
 
 for(let i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++) {
   for(let j = 0; j < inventory[i].shoes.length; j++) {
     arr.push([`${inventory[i].name}, ${inventory[i].shoes[j].name}, ${inventory[i].shoes[j].price}`])
   }
 }
 
  return arr;
}

console.log(renderInventory(currentInventory));
```

A more easier way is to use [`for ... of` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) by taking the objects directly.

```js
function renderInventory(inventory) {
    let arr = [];

    for (const { name, shoes } of inventory)
        for (const shoe of shoes)
            arr.push([`${name}, ${shoe.name}, ${shoe.price}`]);

    return arr;
}

const
    currentInventory = [{ name: 'Brunello Cucinelli', shoes: [{ name: 'tasselled black low-top lace-up', price: 1000 }, { name: 'tasselled green low-top lace-up', price: 1100 }, { name: 'plain beige suede moccasin', price: 950 }, { name: 'plain olive suede moccasin', price: 1050 }] }, { name: 'Gucci', shoes: [{ name: 'red leather laced sneakers', price: 800 }, { name: 'black leather laced sneakers', price: 900 }] }];


console.log(renderInventory(currentInventory));
```

Comment: is that not what I am doing? I'm not sure what you are referencing to here: for(let j = 0; j < inventory[i].shoes.length; j++) {

Comment: no, you have only the length without a comparison with `j`.

Comment: ok I updated it with the j comparison..and it gave me a whole new error that is even longer

Comment: and which one ?

Comment: Expected $.length = 4 to equal 6. Expected $[0].length = 1 to equal 3. Expected $[0][0] = 'Brunello Cucinelli, tasselled black low-top lace-up, 1000' to equal 'Brunello Cucinelli'.....

Comment: do you want a neste array as result with groups of same item names? please add the website of the assignment.

Comment: How long an error is isn't from relevance I would say

Answer (score 0):

In this line you have missed a **comparison**

```
for(let j = 0; inventory[i].shoes.length; j++) {
```

Write this

```
   for(let j = 0;j < inventory[i].shoes.length; j++) {
```

```js
const currentInventory = [
  {
    name: 'Brunello Cucinelli',
    shoes: [
      {name: 'tasselled black low-top lace-up', price: 1000},
      {name: 'tasselled green low-top lace-up', price: 1100},
      {name: 'plain beige suede moccasin', price: 950},
      {name: 'plain olive suede moccasin', price: 1050}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Gucci',
    shoes: [
      {name: 'red leather laced sneakers', price: 800},
      {name: 'black leather laced sneakers', price: 900}
    ]
  }
];

function renderInventory(inventory) {
 let arr = [];
 
 for(let i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++) {
   for(let j = 0; j < inventory[i].shoes.length; j++) {
     arr.push([inventory[i].name, inventory[i].shoes[j].name, inventory[i].shoes[j].price])
   }
 }
 
  return arr;
}

console.log(renderInventory(currentInventory));
```

Comment: ok I corrected that but it threw a whole new error

Comment: which one throws it?

Comment: Expected $.length = 4 to equal 6. Expected $[0].length = 1 to equal 3. Expected $[0][0] = 'Brunello Cucinelli, tasselled black low-top lace-up, 1000' to equal 'Brunello Cucinelli'. ....

Comment: For what do you use this dollar syntax?

Comment: im not using that...that is the direct copy of the failed test is...I believe its an unexpected outcome error

Comment: I mean this template string syntax here   `arr.push([`${inventory[i].name}, ${inventory[i].shoes[j].name}, ${inventory[i].shoes[j].price}`])`

Comment: to interpolate in the array. Its a template literal

Answer (score 0):

You need to write this way instead:

```
for(let i = 0; i < inventory.length-1; i++) {
    // code here
}
```

The reason for the error is that the length property does not necessarily indicate the number of defined values in the array.

```
let array = ['apple', 'banana'];

console.log(array.length);
// Expected result: 2

console.log(array[2]);
// Expected result: undefined
```

This is why the last item was undefined.